# hibernate validator error when @NotEmpty used on return type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

[this](https://github.com/bilak/hibernate-validation-issue) is my sample application with it's [test](https://github.com/bilak/hibernate-validation-issue/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/bilak/hibernatevalidationissue/NotEmptyValidatorTest.java). I've defined some constraints on [repository](https://github.com/bilak/hibernate-validation-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/bilak/hibernatevalidationissue/repository/SimpleRepository.java) as `@NotEmpty`. When I want to call this repository I'm getting following issue

`javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000141: The constraint org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty used ConstraintTarget#IMPLICIT where the target cannot be inferred.`

Do I need to implement validator for `@NotEmpty` or is this a bug in hibernate or my spring-boot application?

**note** when I remove `@NotEmpty` from return type, it works.

Comment: Can you bring back the code in here, it makes the question easier to read (for the test and repo).

Comment: It looks to be a bug in HV as 5.3 and 5.4 both seems to be missing NotEmpty validator implementations. If you'd like to use it on Strings as in your example, you might consider also looking at `@NotBlank` - this one should work fine if the constraint matches your needs. Or I would also recommend to upgrade to Hibernate Validator 6.0. It's the latest version with a lot of improvements. (but in case of 6.0 you would need to do some changes in your configuration though ...)

Comment: Actually looking more into this - `@NotEmpty` constraint from HV is a composite constraint and there's no Validator implementaions for it as it should be using a composition of Size and NotNull validators. And that's what causing this problem (so still looks to be a bug but slightly different, than what I was saying in the previous comment...)

Comment: I've tried to use HV6 but there was some config error and I didn't have time to fix it. So maybe I will look into this, but it's interesant that this "bug" is there for long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into an interesting corner case here, where for a *purely composed* constraint it cannot be determined whether it applies to the parameters or the return value of a method. Back in the time of Bean Validation 1.1 [we decided](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-446) to leave it to implementations to handle this case as it's very rare.

Hibernate Validator allows to resolve this case [by specifying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#_validation_target_specification_for_purely_composed_constraints) `@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.ANNOTATED_ELEMENT)` on the constraint definition. This was added in HV 5.2, but then it seems we forgot to make use of it for `@NotEmpty` and potentially other purely composed constraints defined by HV. Could you therefore please file a bug report in our [JIRA instance](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV)?

Note that you shouldn't have the problem with the `@NotEmpty` defined in Bean Validation 2.0 (HV 6.0), as this isn't declared as a purely composed constraint.

Update: this issue has been fixed in Hibernate Validator 6.0.3.Final (and backported to 5.3.6.Final and 5.4.2.Final).

Comment: Btw. as a work-around it should work if you add a dummy `ConstraintValidator` for `@NotEmpty` via an XML constraint mapping. Its `isValid()` method would always return `true`, but its presence would cause the resolution algorithm to apply the constraint (and thus its composing constraints) to the method return value and not the parameters.

Comment: Thank you I've created [this issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1494)